# Unsure about solution of homogenous ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question regarding the general solution of the ODE:

$x^{(4)}+3x^{(3)}+2x''=0$

To solve this I find the zeros of the char.eq. $r^{4}+3r^{3}+2r^{2}=0$.

Which can be factorized into $r^{2}(r+1)(r+2)=0$

So $r_1=0 \quad \text{(double root)}$ 
$\quad r_2=-1 \quad r_3=-2$

Is the general solution then $x(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-2t}+c_3t$ ?

Im not sure if the theorem in my book satisfies linear independence for this solution, because I only have 3 roots for a fourth degree ODE (where one of the roots has multiplicity 2)? Can the Wronskian be used to determine if it is or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $y = x''$ then you have $y''+3y'+2y = 0$, whose characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2 + 3\lambda + 2 = 0$ and gives $\lambda_1 = -2$ and $\lambda_2 = -1$. You can hence write $y(t) = c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-2t}$. Now solve $x''(t) = c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-2t}$ just integrating and find $x$.

Comment: Okay makes sense, but is it still possible to solve it without a substitution as I tried? Did I make any mistake somewhere along or?

Comment: You are probably missing a constant in your solution. If I integrate twice $x''$ I should get your expression + a constant.

Comment: But how can I deduce that there should be a constant? 

Kinda confused, since the theorem in my book states that if $r_1,..,r_m$ are distinct roots of the coressponding char.eq to the ODE, then the solutions $t^{k}e^{r_{i}t}$ where $k=0,1,...q_{i}-1$, $i=1,2,...,r$ are linearly independent. ($q_i$ stands for the multiplicity of the root)

Comment: Wouldnt that mean that $x=c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-2t}+c_3t$ are lin.independent and hence form a fundamental set of solutions?

Comment: I do not know a general theorem about this, but I know that things like $x''+ax'+bx = 0$ can be solved using the characteristic polynomial as I did above. I have just tried to apply this result to your exercise. This way I find a constant more. In a general statement there might be some discussion about multiple roots of the characteristic polynomial, as your $r_1$ is. Do you see anything about this?

Comment: No I didn't find any discussions about multiple roots of the char.eq thats why I had trouble with this problem..

Comment: I think I understood it now. Since 0 has a multiplicity of 2, $q_{i}-1$=1 and the solution corresponding to the root 0 hence runs through $k=0,1$. So that we obtain a constant when $k=0$.

Comment: Very good. We agree then.